# How do I get Youtube Links to open in the YouTube app and not a browser?

Tags: youtube

Everytime I click a link to a Youtube clip I have to choose which browser to open it in. I'd like them to open in the YouTube android app. Is there a setting somewhere that I can change ...?

Comment: If you're on a device with a newer HTC sense version (3.6 and up), there doesn't appear to be much you can do about it without root (and even then it breaks browser links to phone and maps)

Answer (score 8):

If you have YouTube installed, the YouTube app should be one of the options you get to open the video. When you see this prompt, checking the "Set this option as default" checkbox will make every YouTube link open with the app (you might have to check the option again when opening from multiple browsers, I've had this happen).

Comment: To change the option later or if you accidentally chose the wrong one, you'll find the setting under 'Menu->Manage Applications' then find the browser or YouTube app (whichever you set as the default) and choose 'Clear Defaults'.

Comment: in my 'Manage Applications' the Browser app doesn't have any defaults set.  Does anybody know where those defaults are stored?