# How to make YouTube URLs open in YouTube app rather than browser? (updated for 2022)

Tags: browser, youtube

I'm using Android 12 on a Google Pixel 3. My default browser is Brave. I sometimes also use Chrome.

For many types of links, such as https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6883161994237636609/ , my phone correctly opens the content via the related native app (in this case, LinkedIn).

**I want all YouTube URLs to open via the YouTube app and thought my settings (shown below) would enable this behavior; what is wrong?**

Although many similar questions have been asked before, their old answers haven't helped me in 2022:

- [How do I get Youtube Links to open in the YouTube app and not a browser?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23440/how-do-i-get-youtube-links-to-open-in-the-youtube-app-and-not-a-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Youtube videos open in browser by default](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34873/youtube-videos-open-in-browser-by-default)
- [Open links in corresponding app instead of browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/194218/open-links-in-corresponding-app-instead-of-browser)
- [Force links to open in the app, not the default browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37549/force-links-to-open-in-the-app-not-the-default-browser?noredirect=1&lq=1)

You can see that my settings look appropriate here:

[image]

[image]

P.S. YouTube URLs within email messages in my Gmail app *do* open the YouTube app correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for Brave Browser only and the navigation that is shown below might change in the future because who knows ¯\*(ツ)*/¯.

Try disabling “Video playback in Brave” under ***Settings > Site settings > Media***

PS: Similar settings are available in most popular browsers, messaging apps, etc. All you have to do is fiddle around the settings. And most settings won't break/harm your phone.